# Showing featured image of page's child's children page

Tags: php, post-thumbnails

so i have a page that has children pages acting as categories, that each have children pages themselves (parent > children > children of children). How would I go about showing the featured images of just the children's children on the parent page? This is important because on the second level i.e. parent > children I am using featured images as banners, but do not want them to reflect on the parent page. My existing script shows all children featured images:

```
        <?php
           $projects = get_pages( array('sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'sort_order' => 'ASC', 'child_of' => $post->ID) );  

           if ($projects) {

              foreach( $projects as $project ) { ?>
                <div>
                    <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($project->ID); ?>
                </div>
           <?php }
           }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a solution through trial and error, unfortunately having to resort to custom fields. I added a custom field to every child element i wanted to display and used the code:

```
<?php
   $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'page',
       'meta_key' => 'xxxx',
       'meta_value' => 'xxxx'
    );


    $myPages = new WP_Query($args);
    while ($myPages->have_posts()) : $myPages->the_post(); 
       echo "$post->post_title";
       echo the_post_thumbnail();
    endwhile;

    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

This was done by navigating to the specific pages I want to display and creating a custom field, which adds meta data to the page.